# Noun to name the never ending struggle of getting better at doing something

Tags: word-choice

In my company we are trying to apply a set of techniques to shorten software release delays (among others).

When starting to work toward this goal, we had a set of tasks grouped in a category   called **"CI/CD readiness"**, meaning that we are trying to get up to speed with the basics of this way of working ("CI/CD").

Now, a few months later, we have made some significant progress in implementing some industry standard techniques, but there is still some work to be done, and probably will always be.

For this reason, I'm looking for the last few days for a word to name this: the never ending task of getting better and better at CI/CD.

Also I would like to convey a meaning that we are embarking boldly on this journey.

So far, I have a few ideas but none that seems to describe this exactly: "art", as in "martial art", "proficiency", "improvements".

Do you know of any word that could express all this?

Thanks,

Comment: One that comes to mind is "grind", but that might not be as elegant as you'd like.

Comment: @LarryTang indeed it could be a good one but indeed it's for the workplace and I'm not sure it would be fully welcomed

Comment: Yes, I agree, Kris' answer is more appropriate for a formal situation by far .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**evolve**

> 1. to develop or cause to develop gradually

(Collins via [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/evolve))

> If something evolves or you evolve it, it gradually develops over a period of time into something different and usually more advanced.

([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/evolve))

I'd say it's "**a continously evolving**" process.

Use case:

> CPS, along with the **continuous evolving** IoT, has posed several challenges. (emphasis added)

(*[Evolving IoT and Cyber-Physical Systems: Advancements, Applications, and Solutions](https://scpe.org/index.php/scpe/Call-issue-3-2020)*, in Scalable Computing: Practice & Experience) 
HTH.

Comment: Or possibly "**a continuously improving** process". This gives the idea that things are getting better rather than just changing (evolving).

Comment: @PeterJennings You don't "evolve" into worse. Please look up *evolve*. Note the "usually more advanced". Good Luck.

Comment: I'll use evolvement, the noun made of the verb you recommend